# Google Maps v3 API - Signed In Maps & My Maps support

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I notice you can enable sign-in with the Google Maps V3 API. I wondered, is it possible to display a map created under a users My Maps service on a map configured through the V3 API?

I'm not so sure it is possible having had a hunt around on the web, so thought I'd ask here.

Thanks

Comment: Lol, are you an insider or something? they just announced the my map is coming back to the main google app.. so I guess they will have that in the API soon.. http://www.engadget.com/2015/03/26/google-android-my-maps/

Comment: Well there is nothing in that news article that tells me anything different, so I'm not sure what you are getting at!

Comment: Haha, I was just trying to say if they have it in their map app, I think they will add it back to the api soon? The documentation explained the reason why google disallow to load my map into users map directly was security connect. And clearly google does not think so anymore...? That's what I'm getting at

Answer (score 0):

According to the [KML files on Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/support/kmlmaps#google_my_maps), you can upload a KML file to my maps and at the same time, Google Maps v3 API.

but there is no mention about displaying my maps directly on v3. 
However you can try figure out how to get `mid` and `lid` programmatically and regenerate the share url.